# What's the purpose of ProtoMessage method?

Tags: go, protocol-buffers

when I generate go code from a protocol buffer file, I noticed that each of the generated structs implement the Message interface, https://github.com/golang/protobuf/blob/master/proto/lib.go#L277

For an example of the code that is generated, see https://github.com/google/go-genproto/blob/master/googleapis/rpc/status/status.pb.go#L97

Clearly, the other methods on Message interface, String() and Reset(), have an obvious purpose and the concrete implementation example makes that clear. However, I don't understand the purpose of the ProtoMessage() method. The method takes no parameters and returns no arguments, so why is it there?

Comment: At a guess (hence why this is a comment, not an answer), I would say it's to make sure you don't accidentally implement the Message interface. With only the `String` and `Reset` methods, too many things will match. eg: a `bytes.Buffer` would implement the interface if `ProtoMessage()` wasn't required.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quoting from official doc: [Protocol Buffers: Go Generated Code:](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/go-generated)

> Given a simple message declaration:
>
> ```
> message Foo {}
> ```
>
> the protocol buffer compiler generates a struct called `Foo`. A `*Foo` implements the [Message](https://godoc.org/github.com/golang/protobuf/proto#Message) interface. See the inline comments for more information.
>
> ```
> type Foo struct {
> }
>
> // Reset sets the proto's state to default values.
> func (m *Foo) Reset()         { *m = Foo{} }
>
> // String returns a string representation of the proto.
> func (m *Foo) String() string { return proto.CompactTextString(m) }
>
> // ProtoMessage acts as a tag to make sure no one accidentally implements the
> // proto.Message interface.
> func (*Foo) ProtoMessage()    {}
> ```
>
> Note that all of these members are always present; the `optimize_for` option does not affect the output of the Go code generator.

This is a (similar) technique described in Go official [FAQ: How can I guarantee my type satisfies an interface?](https://golang.org/doc/faq#guarantee_satisfies_interface)

> If you wish the users of an interface to explicitly declare that they implement it, you can add a method with a descriptive name to the interface's method set. For example:
>
> ```
> type Fooer interface {
>     Foo()
>     ImplementsFooer()
> }
> ```
>
> A type must then implement the `ImplementsFooer` method to be a `Fooer`, clearly documenting the fact and announcing it in [godoc](https://golang.org/cmd/godoc/)'s output.
>
> ```
> type Bar struct{}
> func (b Bar) ImplementsFooer() {}
> func (b Bar) Foo() {}
> ```
>
> Most code doesn't make use of such constraints, since they limit the utility of the interface idea. Sometimes, though, they're necessary to resolve ambiguities among similar interfaces.

So the `ProtoMessage()` method basically has 2 purposes:

- The main purpose is as documented in the generated code: to make sure you don't pass a value for protobuf serialization / deserialization which otherwise (without this method) would implement the [`proto.Message`](https://godoc.org/github.com/golang/protobuf/proto#Message) interface but is not a "real" protobuf message value:

  > **ProtoMessage acts as a tag to make sure no one accidentally implements the proto.Message interface.**
- And it also documents the fact that the type is a (implements) `Message`. This may not have a real value at first as the code is generated and you should not bother much with it, but code analyzers and Go IDE's may make good use of it; and it also appears in generated docs.